# MSSQL PDO query returns always 0

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm using mssql database to build an application. To connect with the database I use

`$db = new PDO('mssql:host=' . $CONFIG['dbserver'] . ';dbname=' .
$CONFIG['lin2db'],$CONFIG['dbuser'], $CONFIG['dbpass']);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

And I've got this function inside a class.

```
public function getGameAccounts($macc_id){
$query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_account WHERE macc_id = ? ");
$query->bindValue(1, $macc_id); 
try{
    $query->execute();
    $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

    if($rows <= $CONFIG['gamemaxaccounts']){
        return true;
        }else{
            return false;
             }

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
        }
}
```

The variable $macc_id contains a number ex. 40 . When I call this function I always get 0. I Figured out that if I pass the variable directly inside the query it works fine. All the solutions I found were to remove ' ' . I don't use any. What's the cause?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get 0 beacuse you always get false (0).

```
    if($rows <= $CONFIG['gamemaxaccounts']){
    return true;
    }else{
        return false;
         }
```

you function dont see variable $CONFIG['gamemaxaccounts'] and you always get false;

Comment: And w/o the $CONFIG['gamemaxaccounts'] it returns 0 again.

Comment: use var_dump on your result and be sure you put variable $OCNFIG into function public function getGameAccounts($macc_id, $CONFIG)

Comment: Thank you! Finally that was it! I passed correctly the value and it wokred